# How to query the complex Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

```
    import mongoose from "mongoose";
    const hotelSchema =new  mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "Please enter hotel name"],
        trim:true

    },
    gst:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "Please enter hotel GST"],
    },
    featuredHotel:{
        type:String,
        default:"disabled"
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "Please enter hotel description"],
    },
    primaryContactNumber:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true, "Please enter primary contact number"]
    },
    alternateContactNumber:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true, "Please enter primary contact number"]
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "Please enter email"]
    },
    address:{
        buildingNo:{
            type:String,
            required:[true, "Please enter the building number"]
        },
        streetName:{
            type:String,
            required:[true, "Please enter the street name"]
        },
        area:String,
        city:{
            type:String,
            required:[true, "Please enter the city"]
        },
        state:{
            type:String,
            required:[true, "Please enter the state"],
        },
        country:{
            type:String,
            default:"India"
        },
        pinCode:{
            type:Number,
            required:[true, "Please enter the pinCode"]
        }
    },
    rooms:[
        {
            name:{
                type:String,
                required:[true, "Please enter the room type"]
            },
            cost:[{price:{
                type:Number,
                required:[true, "Please enter room price"],
            },
            type:{
                type:String,
                required:[true, "Please enter the price type"]
            },
            quantity:{
                type:Number,
                required:[true, "Please enter room quantity"],
            },
            }],
            category:[{
                    type:String,
                    required:[true, "Please enter the room category"]
                
            }],
            status:{
                type:String,
                required:[true, "Please enter the room status"]
            },
            note:String
        }
    ],
    
    images:[
        { public_id:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
        },
        url:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
        }}
    ],
    hotelCategory:[{
            type:String,
            required:[true, "Please enter the hotel category"]
    }],
    amenities:[{
            type:String,
            required:[true, "Please enter the amenities"]
    }],
    hotelPolicy:[
        {
                type:String,
                required:[true, "Please enter the hotel policy"]}
    ],
    cancelPolicy:[
        {
                type:String,
                required:[true, "Please enter the cancel policy"]
        },
     ],
     placesOfInterest:[
        {
                type:String,
        },
     ],
     ratings:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    numOfReviews:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    status:{
        type:String,
        default:"disabled"
    },
    reviews:[
        {
            user:{
                type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref:"User",
            },
            name:{
                type:String,
            },
            rating:{
                type:Number,
            },
            comment:{
                type:String,
            }
        }
    ],
    user_id:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:"User",
    },
    isApproved:{
        type:String,
        default:"pending"
    },
    isDeleted:{
        type:String,
        default:"NA"
    },
    createdAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    },
    updatedAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }

});


export const Hotel = mongoose.model("Hotel", hotelSchema);
```

I need to query the above schema and filter the documents.

Filter scenarios are

1. Fetch all the documents with a city under the address equal to some given value.
2. Sort the documents on the basis of price under rooms.
3. fetch the documents with type under rooms equal to the given value.

Similarly, I would like to add other complex conditions.

Comment: To get data from MongoDB, you should look into MongoDB aggregation queries. If you have defined the fields in your MongoDB collection properly in mongoose schema and if you use proper MongoDB aggregation query, you will get the results as you want